# Gedit plugin development in Python

Tags: python, plugins, gedit

Does anyone know where information about writing gedit plugins can be found? I'm interested in writing them in Python. I know of [Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo), but it isn't very good. Besides the code of writing a plugin that does nothing, I can't seem to find more information. I started to look at other people's code, but I think this shouldn't be the natural way of writing plugins.

Can someone help?

Comment: Seriously, what's the problem in starting with other people's code?

Comment: The problem is that you have to make some assumptions ( which may turn out to be incorrect )

Comment: Well, that's at least how science works, and see where it got them;)

Comment: Have you checked out [http://sp2hari.com/gedit-plugin/](http://sp2hari.com/gedit-plugin/) ? I think this is as thorough as you're going to get, without poring through other people's code.

Comment: What kind of plugin? The wiki link + PyGTK documentation should be enough, no?

Comment: When I started working on my gedit plugin, I used the howto you gave a link to, also startign with [this URL](http://www.russellbeattie.com/blog/my-first-gedit-plugin). Then it was looking at other plugins code... I'm sorry to say that, but for me this topic is poorly documented and best and fastest way is to get a pluging done that actually does something.